# hide view just above tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am having a upperview with height 60 and i have placed tableview at y = 60.I want when i scroll the table my upperview should be hide and when i scroll down it should be visible again.But i can not make this upperview as header of tableview.Please help me how i can i detect the direction of scrollview within tableview that is it moving up or down.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    int scrollPosition =   scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if(upperview.frame.size.height<scrollPosition>1 && moveDirection = movingup){
        //code to make hide
    }else if(upperview.frame.size.height==scrollPosition>1 && moveDirection = movingDown){
        //code to show again
    }
       // But i have no idea how can i get this direction moveDirection = movingup or  moveDirection = movingDown
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why can you not make your `upperview` header of the tableview? That's what it's made for!

Comment: Make Your upperview as your tableview header view.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this tried but it always had the problem that the overlaying view could not gain the acceleration of the scroll view.  It would mismatch during very quick changes of scrolling speed by the user.

If you cannot use the table's header view, you could add your view as a subview of the scroll view above coordinate zero, then change the UIScrollView's contentInset to allow it to scroll into sight.